# How to make a ANTBlazor modal to appear from left to right?

Tags: css, .net, blazor, ant-blazor

I am using AntBlazor https://antblazor.com/en-US/components/modal#ant-blazor-da44632c-cca6-4a40-8c4c-373c9f20689c

How can I slide the modal from right to left?

#### ModalSlider

```
<Button Type="primary" OnClick="()=> _visible2 = true">
    Sample Modal

</Button>
<Modal 
       @bind-Visible="_visible2"
       Style=" position: fixed;right: 0;">
    <p>some contents...</p>
    <p>some contents...</p>
    <p>some contents...</p>
</Modal>
```

```
@code {
string title = "BasicModal";
bool _visible2 = false;
}
```

By specifying the style =" position: fixed;right: 0;" the modal appears right but how can I add the sliding effect? Also need to fit the modal covering the entire window